# Want to copy all attributes of a struct member to another in same struct in C

Tags: c, struct, copy, member

I have the following structs and I want to copy all the attributes and structs inside 
`sch[j]` to `sch[j-1]`.

I want to ask if it is possible do it like this?

```
sch[j-1]=sch[j];
```

Please say yes!!! Otherwise, can you explain how can I do it? As if you are explaining to a dumb? Because I am pretty new in coding. Actually, if it is easier to write, I may prefer to copy some elements of schedules struct to a new struct in the same type.

```
struct modevariables{
    float xvalue1;
    float xvalue2;
};

struct ActivityVariables{
    int es,ec,ls,lc,discritized;
    int relxd1,relxdmode1,relxd2,relxdmode2,cr,noofpred;
    int chmode1,chmode2,ilpr1ptime,ilpr2ptime;
    float lpr1cost,fs,stime5,lpr2cost,lpr1ptime,lpr2ptime;
    float lpr1fs,ilprfs,lpr2fs,stime1,stime2;
    modevariables modev[22];
};

struct schedules{
    float WF1,WF2;
    int TC1,TC2,seeded;
    double tcplex1,tcplex5,tgams5cagir,timewhile,orjsch;
    ActivityVariables actv[52];
    int type;  
    int dominance;
    int dominates;
};
```

Comment: Yes, you can assign structs to each other in C. You do NOT have to copy over each member of a struct. You could do that of course, or try to use memcpy, but you don't have to.

Comment: You need to add the struct keyword before the `modevariables` and `ActivityVariables` instantiations. BTW I don't see sch[] anywhere in your code.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been quicker to try it out?  The compiler won't bite you if you do something that isn't allowed.

Comment: Thank you Orwell. Sorry to bother you. I could not be sure.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, you say that but there are stories of demons flying out noses all over the internet.

Comment: It looks like you are missing one of your structure types.  You have multiple pairs of members: 'relxd1' and 'relxd2'; 'relxdmode1' and 'relxdmode2'; 'chmode1' and 'chmode2'; 'ilpr1ptime' and 'ilpr2ptime'; 'lpr1cost' and 'lpr2cost'; 'lpr1ptime' and 'lpr2ptime'; 'lpr1fs' and 'lpr2fs'; 'stime1' and 'stime2'.  Surely, that suggests there should be two instances of a structure type in here.

Comment: He is still missing the struct keyword twice (and the sch[] definition) so might be compiling with a C++ (or worse: Microsoft) compiler. (or even worse: not at all)

Comment: I am compiling with c++ in codeblocks.. It was working with no trouble. Thank you for the comments.

Comment: If you're compiling with C++, why is the question tagged C?

Comment: Because my code is C, I only know C. I compile it in c++ only because I was not able to compile it in C. Maybe the reason was wilplasser's answer I don't know. As I said I am new and no expert.

Comment: Well, you only got away without the `struct` prefixes because you used a C++ compiler; a C compiler would give you an error.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can I also got away from freeing nodes in a linked list by using C++ compiler? I probably should not be using C++, but still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may copy one struct to another struct of the same type (including two elements of the same array) with an assignment statement.

Comment: I want to ask one more question about this struct copy. I did not want to open a new topic since it is highly related. I am repatedly sorting,inserting, deleting elements from "sch" struct. And I thought rather than shifting this huge sch struct members, I could use an integer list array, storing the relative positions of sch structs. However I am having difficulty on that. I wonder if this list array was necessary at the first place. Is sch[j-1]=sch[j] type of copying time consuming? Or does it just changes the index with no computational burden?

Comment: @user1887909: Assigning one structure to another copies the structures. The compiler does not generate code to track the indices. Sorting or otherwise permuting elements would typically be done via an array of pointers or indices; one would sort the pointers or indices and not move the actual structures. Inserting and deleting cannot easily be done with an array, whether an array of pointers or an array of structures, since an insert or delete anywhere other than the end of the array requires moving other elements.

Comment: @user1887909: For operations such as inserting or deleting, you need more involved data structures such as linked lists, trees, or hash maps. Discussing those calls for at least another question, possibly more.

Comment: Thank you Eric, I do not have time to learn those other more involved structures. I know that I need to move other elements and I can live with that. But I am confused, since I do not know much. I understand that debugger copies the whole memory of sch[j] to [j-1] without any index logic. So bigger the sch[] struct size higher the burden? Or "one would sort the pointers or indices and not move the actual structures" implies it does not copy the whole structure it just changes their indices. Therefore it does not matter to use int *list or directly using 'sch[j-1]=sch[j];'

Comment: @user1887909: It is up to you to specify what to do. If you write `sch[j-1]=sch[j]`, the compiler (not the debugger) is largely compelled to write instructions that copy the whole structure (which may be done with a bulk copy of the bytes or may be done with element-by-element assignments; the compiler will decide). If you write code with an array of pointers and write assignments of the pointers and not assignments of the structures, then only the pointers will be changed.

Comment: Thank you again:) It seems that I need to learn linked lists.